# Discord.py List all server names where the bot is in

Tags: python, discord.py

I made a bot but I want the bot to make list all the server names where it is when you type a command.
Can any one help me, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
await ctx.send('\n'.join(guild.name for guild in bot.guilds))
```

Just remember to pass an intent with guilds enabled in your bot's constructor

Answer (score 1):

```
@commands.command()
async def servers(self, ctx):
    activeservers = client.guilds
    for guild in activeservers:
        await ctx.send(guild.name)
        print(guild.name)
```

*This code should work*

Answer (score 1):

```
@client.command()
async def server(ctx):
  servers = list(client.guilds)
  for server in servers:
    await ctx.send(server.name)
```

it works for me...